# What is "quantum gas"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, bose-einstein-condensate

I could not find a satisfying definition of this term from anywhere. Also, Can you please give some introductory level references to understand quantum gas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To put it simply, a quantum gas (or quantum fluid) is a system made of indistinguishable particles, as opposed to a classical gas where you assume that you can differentiate one component from other (that means that in a classical gas you could label every single constituent of the gas theoretically, and always know its position and momentum, whereas for a quantum gas you cannot know such information for each particle individually).

Very generally, fluids exhibit a quantum behaviour at low temperatures and/or high densities and the classical gas model is a good approximation for high temperatures and/or low density. However, don't get confused: there are no classical particles in nature and the classical gas is nothing but a simplification that under some circumstances can be used to describe reality.

Depending on the wavefunction simmetry of the particles that constitute the gas, the gas follows a different statistic, namely Bose-Einstein statistics for bosons and Fermi-Dirac for fermions.

From a macroscopic point of view, we usually call quantum fluids to those that exhibit some kind of "quantum" macroscopic behaviour such as superfluidity or superconductivity.

To start studying quantum gases I think that it would be necessary to have some background in statistical mechanics and also some ideas of quantum mechanics.

For the statistical mechanics part:

**H.B. Callen.** *Thermodynamics and an introduction to Thermostatistics.*

**S. R. A. Salinas.** *Introduction to Statistical Physics.*

**D. J. Amit, Y. Verbin, R. Tzafriri.** *Statistical physics. An introductory course*

And maybe more advanced options are

**R. Balian.** *From microphysics to macrophysics.*

**M. Kardar.** *Statistical physics of particles.*

And for the quantum mechanics part I'd reccomend you

**Cohen-Tannoudji C., Diu B., Laloe F.** *Quantum mechanics, vol. 1 and vol. 2*